# Subscribe to packages in puppet

Tags: dependencies, puppet, subscribe

Consider I have a profile that installs a package. After installation, it runs some `exec` commands. But these commands need to run only once when the package is first installed.

```
  package { 'package1':
    ensure => 'present'
  }

  exec { 'signal_package_conf':
        command     => 'systemctl restart package.service',
        path        => '/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin',
        refreshonly => true,
        subscribe   => Package['package1'],
      }
```

**But suppose this particular package gets installed as a dependency for another package in another profile.**

When puppet comes to the `package1` resource, it will find that the package is already installed and will not install it again. Since puppet would not know of this implicit package dependency, will the subscription to the package still work and execute the command in the `exec` resource?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer is in two parts, to address two possible interpretations of your query about refresh relationships in general.

**Refresh events and ordering from other classes**

Let me try to rewrite what I understand your question to be in more general terms. You are asking:

*Question*

Suppose that Exec resource Y *subscribes* with `refreshonly => true` to a resource X in class A. Then suppose that resource Z *requires* the same resource X in class B.

In other words, imagine this code:

```
class b () {
  notify { 'Z':
    require => Notify['X'],
  }
}

class a () {
  notify { 'X': }
  exec { 'Y':
    command     => '/bin/echo Y',
    refreshonly => true,
    subscribe   => Notify['X'],
  }
}

include a
include b
```

Is it possible for the final ordering to be X, Z, Y, and if so, will the *refresh* event definitely reach Exec resource Y, considering that X and Y could be separated by Z in time?

*Answer*

Yes, and yes. Recall that Puppet builds a directed acyclic graph, and it computes the final ordering from traversing that graph. This code leads to two possible orderings in time, X, Y, Z and X, Z, Y (try it a few times using `puppet apply /tmp/code.pp --ordering=random`).

But that's ok, because Puppet also tracks a queue of resources that have received a refresh event.

**What if package A is installed as a dependency of package B by the package manager outside of Puppet**

It's also possible that you are asking about RPM or other package-manager-level dependencies that exist outside of Puppet. If so, naturally, Puppet can't know about these.

If so, yes, the refresh event would not be sent if the package manager (or anything else outside of Puppet) satisfied the subscription.

Comment: I saw that option, but if I set `reinstall_on_refresh ` to true, wont it also re-install every time puppet runs?

Comment: As I mentioned, only if reinstallable is also implemented, and at this time, it's only implemented for `provider => portage`. If you're on Gentoo, perhaps that's a real issue?

Comment: In your example, classes `a` and `b` will be managed by puppet. What I meant was when I do `package { 'package1':  ensure => present }` in another profile that installs as a dependency `package2`(this is done using `yum` in my case and installation of `package2` is not known to puppet). Now if I have an `exec` that subscribes to `package2` will it still run?

Comment: Yes, see the third part.

Comment: **Since puppet would not know of this implicit ... dependency", that assumption there is wrong. Because Puppet builds a graph and tracks during the run which resources receive refresh events, Puppet always "knows" about the implicit dependency.)
**
Even if that implicit dependency is created outside of puppet(in this case by `yum`)?

Comment: Yes, because Puppet knows nothing about what goes on inside yum.

Comment: i.e. Puppet only knows about implicit dependencies if they are defined inside the Puppet manifest code. If the dependency is "implicit" in the sense of "implied via yum", then you're right - Puppet knows nothing about that sort of implicit dependency.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183626/discussion-between-leoorion-and-alex-harvey).

Comment: re: the first point: I do not believe the asker is attempting to refresh a `package` resource, and I do not see an edit history in the question to indicate that. Another super minor point is that you can also enable `refreshable` with a method in the type that invokes something specific in the provider.

Comment: You're completely right. Not sure what I was thinking. I updated the answer to delete the bit that shouldn't be there.